Measuring Voltage in floors and walls
I am doing some electrical rewiring in a old home (1940s) as some of the wiring is looking very dodgy (most of the wires still have cotton insulation). I have a basic understanding of electrical wiring and physics, but nothing fancy.
I found that there is a low voltage (12V-36V) when i connect a Volt Tester to doorknobs and door locks.
I pulled the breakers as a precaution, but want to know if it dangerous. I know that any measurement below 36V is safe but it is a rather humid climate (French coastal region) and i spent the whole day on it. (i do have young kids).
I assume that it's faulty wiring in the walls (read somewhere that the old cotton wiring tends to harden and crack), so I'm planning to rip it all out in stages.
Advice would be appreciated.

I think you mean low voltage (12V to 36V).  How are you connecting your voltage meter to the door knobs?  Wiring from the 40's wouldn't normally be falling apart in the walls.  Get someone who knows what they are doing just to check it out.

Have you checked for any actual current? It's quite common if you're using a high impedance tester that it will read some voltage when connected to anything metal that can serve as an antenna.

Well I think its coming though old wiring, Most of the wiring is worked/hidden into the door frames and other wood paneling. And the current was gone when i pulled the breaker, so....

"I.. found that these is a low current (12V-36V) when i connect a Volt Tester to doorknobs and door locks." Likely, there is a small capacitively coupled voltage, at negligible current. However, you have neither the correct instrument or technique to measure it. If concerned, get a licensed electrician to examine that wiring.

What instrument are you using to measure this?

is it AC or DC ?

@Traveler France uses 220V 50Hz AC.

@ThreePhaseEel I'm using a tester screwdriver (with a small screen indicating voltage amounts).

If you hold your screwdriver instrument very close to the wall outlet, but not touching it, what do you read ?

@Traveler Nothing on the meter. That said, it looks like that the wall outlets and lights aren't earthed. Wiring is all 2 pair (L/N) and outlets are all just 2 pin. Also lights and outlets are on the same circuit. Even found some porcelain breakers. Could this be the cause?
